# Invisible (!) data on NAS machine

Tags: backup, storage

I am running a Thecus N7510 NAS machine, with 4 HDD in a RAID 10 configuration and one more as a "hot stand by". This machine is used for a variety of purposes, excluding backup up until now.

Lately I tried to use the DeltaCopy utitlity to take incremental backups of some data on one of my servers. The utility reports the task completed successfully, and indeed, when I check with the included file manager (via the webui of the Thecus), the folder is there, as it should be. The funny/strange part is that when I try to view the data from any of the Windows machines that mount that volume, everything is there, as before, but not the folder with the backup.

Does anyone have any idea what has transpired?

Comment: Maybe a NTFS permissions issue with Access-Based Enumeration enabled ?

Comment: Just had the idea that it was permission based. Fixed it.